# Can you *read* leveldb data without the proper comparator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, indexeddb, leveldb

I'm trying to access leveldbs generated by Chrome storing indexeddbs. I get keys and values. But they are either in an unknown encoding - I've tried many ways to detect them - or they are scrambled in some way.

```
import plyvel    
db = plyvel.DB(dirname, comparator=cmp, comparator_name="idb_cmp1")
for key, value in db:
    print(key) 
    print(value)
```

I don't mind if the keys are in random order as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35142175/7195400). But it would be nice to get the keys and values in a readable fashion. I'm not dealing with binary data in the leveldb, either.

I'm using plyvel in python to iterate over the db. This answer might be related: [LevelDB C iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36262408/7195400)

Comment: I guess you can't. "The design of LevelDB is such that the same comparator must be used when opening a LevelDB that was used to create it." https://codereview.chromium.org/213263004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may fake it by passing exactly the same comparator name to a custom comparator in plyvel. that comparator may work differently from the one originally used to create the database. that would get you past the first hurdle i guess.

but since leveldb does not provide a read-only mode of operation, there may be a background thread kicking in to do some compaction while you read the database. and since the comparator is mishaving, this can lead to data loss and destruction of your database.